# Is $\ln\left( \frac{1+2x}{1-2x}\right)$ an odd or even function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logarithms, even-and-odd-functions

> Is $$f:\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) \to \mathbb{R}, \ x \mapsto \ln\left( \frac{1+2x}{1-2x}\right)$$ an odd or even function?

The function can be decomposed this way:

$$f(x)=\ln(1+2x)-\ln(1-2x)$$

[image: [Graph of the function]]

It seems that this function is an odd function but I dont know how to justify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A odd function must satisfy the equation $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

Let $x \in \left(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$.
Then we have, as you rightly observed
\begin{align*}
-f(x)
= \ln(1 - 2x) - \ln(1 + 2x)
= \ln(1 + 2(-x)) - \ln(1 - 2(-x))
= f(-x).
\end{align*}

Note that a function being odd graphically corresponds to **rotational symmetry**. Similarly to the graph of $x \mapsto x^3$ (the standard example in my opinion), when you rotate the graph 180° with respect to the origin (alternatively flip over the $y$- and then the $x$-axis), you end up with the same graph.

Comment: so the function doesn't need to be defined in all $\mathbb{R}$ to be an odd or even function?

Comment: That's correct. You could check out the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#cite_note-2), where the above mentioned property has to be valid for all $x$ **in the domain of $f$**.